# first order differential equation help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x'=\frac{t-x}t, t>0$$

I tried to solve it by:

$x'=1-\frac{x}t$

$\int dx=\int(1-\frac{x}t)dt$

$x=t-x\ln t+C$

$x=\frac{t}{1+lnt} +C$

But this doesn't seem right. What am I doing wrong? Also I'm supposed to determine the maximal interval around t=1, but how do I get rid of $C$?

Comment: You can't just integrate $x(t)/t$ with respect to $t$, $x$ is the function you are trying to solve for. You can check your solution is wrong by taking the derivative of both sides. Try using an integrating factor.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Write the DE as
$$x't+x=t$$
then it becomes
$$(xt)'=t$$

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You are treating $x$ as a constant when you integrate $\frac x t$. $x$ is a fucntion of $t$.

Here is the correct solution: the equation can be written as $(tx)'=t$. Hence $tx= \frac {t^{2}} 2+C$. So $x(t)=\frac t 2 +\frac C t$.

Comment: Thank you! But why does $(tx)'=t$ work? Is it just a general rule?

Comment: $(tx)'=tx'+x$ by product rule and the given equation shows that $tx'+x=t$ so we get $(tx)'=t$.